# Pickomino game - how is my structure?

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I'm new to programming. This is a game with 8 dice called Pickomino in English, Regenwormen in Dutch and Heckmeck in German. It's mainly a dice throwing game.

What I want to do (and not achieved yet) is to improve the autoplayer. But first I want to improve my existing code.

It's the first thing I've made in Python, so I'm sure I've done a lot of things very wrong. I feel like reinventing the wheel, which is good for getting a grasp of the matter but not very efficient. This is also the first time I've used a class.

For the rules of the game please check this interesting [website](https://frozenfractal.com/blog/2015/5/3/how-to-win-at-pickomino/) from a C++ programmer.

```
"""

threshold for each player : the chance of surving another throw of dice.
if threshold is low (say 50%), the player accepts more risk not to survive.
threshold of 60% means player would throw again if risk of ruin is less than
40%

"""
import random
import pandas as pd

number_of_dice = 8
free_sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'W']
score = 0
TILES = [x for x in range(21, 36)]
TILESoriginal = [x for x in range(21, 36)]
WORMS = [1]*4 + [2] * 4 + [3] * 4 + [4] * 4
TILES.append('X')
throw_number = 1
turn_number = 1
winning = []
win_tiles = []
cols = ['winner', 'threshold']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
playerID = 0
overallWinners = []
stay_in_turn = True


class player:
    def __init__(self, playername, threshold):
        self.name = playername
        self.human = False
        self.own_tiles = []
        self.tactic = 'normal'
        self.threshold = threshold

    def throw_dice(self, number_of_dice):
        self.thrown_dice = []
        for x in range(number_of_dice):
            self.thrown_dice.append(random.randint(1, 6))
        return self.thrown_dice

    def orden_dices_in_dict(self, dicelist):
        self.hand = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 'W': 0}
        for keys in self.hand:
            self.hand[keys] = dicelist.count(keys)
            self.hand['W'] = dicelist.count(6)
        return self.hand

    def calculate_score(self, score, points):
        self.score = score + points
        return self.score

    def auto_mx_point(self, hand, possible_sides):
        mx_pick = []
        for pos_sides in possible_sides:
            mx_pick.append(hand[pos_sides] * pos_sides)
        if isinstance(mx_pick[-1], str):
            worms = mx_pick[-1].count('W')
            del mx_pick[-1]
            mx_pick.append(worms * 5)
        mx = max(mx_pick)
        mx_index = mx_pick.index(mx)
        print(f'{players[playerID].name} picks {possible_sides[mx_index]}')
        return possible_sides[mx_index]


def add_human():
    add_human = input('A human player joining? (y/n)  ')
    if add_human.upper() == 'Y':
        while True:
            who = input(f'Play with Albert, Boris or Chris? (a/b/c) ')
            if who.upper() == 'A':
                albert.human = True
                break
            if who.upper() == 'B':
                boris.human = True
                break
            if who.upper() == 'C':
                chris.human = True
                break
            print("I don't understand. A, B or C")


def create_stealList(players):
    stealList = []
    for play in players:
        stealList.append(0)
    return stealList


def update_stealList(players, stealList):
    nr_of_players_min1 = (len(players))
    for x in range(0, nr_of_players_min1):
        if players[x].own_tiles:
            stealList[x] = players[x].own_tiles[-1]
        else:
            stealList[x] = 0
    return stealList


def work_with_int_and_string(decided):
    # humans only
    if decided.upper() != 'W':
        decided = int(decided)
    else:
        decided = decided.upper()
    return decided


def print_flathand(hand, playerID):
    flat = []
    for key in hand:
        flat.append(str(key) * hand[key],)
    flat = ''.join(str(e) for e in flat)
    print(f'{players[playerID].name} throws ' + flat)


def possible_sides_to_pick(hand, free_sides):
    thrown_numbers = [key for key in hand if hand[key] > 0]
    return [x for x in thrown_numbers if x in free_sides]


def calculate_points(hand, pick_one):
    if pick_one != 'W':
        points = pick_one * hand[pick_one]
    elif pick_one == 'W':
        points = 5 * hand[pick_one]
    return points


def found_the_W(free_sides_of_dice):
    if 'W' not in free_sides_of_dice:
        return True
    return False


def stop_rolling_again_question():
    """This function asks if human user will throw again"""
    stop_or_not = input('Roll again? (y/n) .. ')
    if stop_or_not.upper() == "N":
        return False
    return True


def survival_rate(free_sides, dice_left):
    free = len(free_sides)
    notfree = 6 - free
    notfreepower = notfree ** dice_left
    allsixsides = 6 ** dice_left
    deadrate = notfreepower / allsixsides
    return int(100 * (1 - deadrate))


def new_nr_of_dice(hand, pick):
    return sum(hand.values()) - hand[pick]


def is_turn_over(number_of_dice_left, free_sides_left):
    if number_of_dice_left and free_sides_left:
        return False  # not dead, because dice left and sides left
    return True


def find_tile(tiles, lastscore):
    while True:
        if lastscore in tiles:
            break
        lastscore = lastscore - 1
    return lastscore


def remove_last_tile(tiles):
    last_tiles = -1
    while True:
        if isinstance(tiles[last_tiles], int):
            tiles[last_tiles] = 'X'
            break
        else:
            last_tiles -= 1
    return tiles


def reset_vars():
    number_of_dice = 8
    free_sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'W']
    score = 0
    return number_of_dice, free_sides, score


def reset_tiles(playerID):
    TILES = [x for x in range(21, 36)]
    TILES.append('X')
    players[playerID].own_tiles = []
    throw_number = 1
    turn_number = 1
    winnaar = ""
    return TILES, players[playerID].own_tiles,\
        throw_number, turn_number, winnaar


def check_first_tiles_int(first_tile):
    if len(first_tile) < 1:
        print('tiles empty!')
        return True
    return isinstance(first_tile[0], int)


def give_back_tile(number, TILES):
    TILES.insert(0, number)
    TILES = [n for n in TILES if isinstance(n, int)]
    TILES.sort()
    TILES.append('X')
    return TILES


def picked_sides(free_sides):
    taken = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'W']
    picked = [e for e in taken if e not in free_sides]
    picked = ''.join(str(e) for e in picked)
    return picked


def string_not_list(lst):
    return ''.join(str(e) for e in lst)


def min_tiles_calc(TILES):
    lowest_tile = []
    lowest_tile.append(min(n for n in TILES if isinstance(n, int)))
    print(f'lowest tiles is {lowest_tile[0]}')
    return lowest_tile


def score_high(score, min_tiles):
    if score >= min_tiles:
        return True
    return False


def next_player(players, playerID):
    playerID += 1
    if playerID == len(players):
        playerID = 0
    return playerID


def most_worms(players):
    # calculate most worms
    total_worms = []
    for playerID in players:
        ownWorms = []
        for tile in playerID.own_tiles:
            spot = TILESoriginal.index(tile)
            ownWorms.append(WORMS[spot])
        print(f'Worms {playerID.name} = {sum(ownWorms)}')
        total_worms.append(sum(ownWorms))
    winner = (total_worms.index(max(total_worms)))
# check draw
    if total_worms.count(max(total_worms)) > 1:
        print('draw in worms')
        draw = []
        for play1 in players:
            draw.append(sum(play1.own_tiles))
        winner = draw.index(max(draw))
    print(f'{players[winner].name} is the winner')
    return players[winner].name


def winner_count(list, players):
    for play in players:
        print(f'{play.name} won {list.count(play.name)} times')


def steal_possible(score, stealList):
    if score in stealList:
        if stealList.index(score) != playerID:
            return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    albert = player('Albert', 66)
    boris = player('Boris', 66)
    chris = player('Chris', 66)
    players = [albert, boris, chris]
    stealList = create_stealList(players)
    number_of_games = int(input(f'Number of games? For auto players mainly '))
    add_human()

    for i in range(0, number_of_games):
        playerID = random.randint(0, 2)  # random start of player
        i += 1
        for singleplayers in players:
            singleplayers.own_tiles = []
        stealList = create_stealList(players)  # rest stealList
        while check_first_tiles_int(TILES):  # the main loop of the game

            while True:  # the loop of throwing dice and picking numbers
                fail = False  # at start of throwing, there is no fail yet
                THRESHOLD = players[playerID].threshold
                #  dice are thrown here for first time
                thrown = players[playerID].throw_dice(number_of_dice)
                hand = players[playerID].orden_dices_in_dict(thrown)
                print_flathand(hand, playerID)
                # next step, pick a number if possible
                possible_sides = possible_sides_to_pick(hand, free_sides)
                if possible_sides:
                    # dice are thrown, and able to pick a number (or R)
                    if not players[playerID].human:
                        pick_one = players[playerID].auto_mx_point(hand, possible_sides)  # max pick
                        free_sides.remove(pick_one)
                        number_of_dice = new_nr_of_dice(hand, pick_one)
                        points = calculate_points(hand, pick_one)
                    else:
                        while True:
                            # routine for human question of picking a side
                            print(f'Possible choices : {possible_sides}')
                            pick_one = input(f'Which one will you pick? :')
                            pick_one = work_with_int_and_string(pick_one)
                            if pick_one in possible_sides_to_pick(hand, free_sides):  # valid choice
                                free_sides.remove(pick_one)
                                number_of_dice = new_nr_of_dice(hand, pick_one)
                                points = calculate_points(hand, pick_one)
                                print(f'Points is {points}')
                                break
                            else:
                                print("Sorry, that isn't possible \n")
                else:
                    fail = True
                    break    
    #  after throwing, and picking a side - calculate score etc
                score = players[playerID].calculate_score(score, points)
                print(f'Score is {score}, dice left = {number_of_dice}, picked sides = {picked_sides(free_sides)} ')
                if is_turn_over(number_of_dice, free_sides): # out of dice or sides
                    # check here if score is high enough
                    if found_the_W(free_sides):
                        if score_high(score, min_tiles_calc(TILES)[0]):
                            fail = False
                        elif steal_possible(score, stealList):
                            fail = False
                        else:
                            fail = True
                        break
                    print('no W found')
                    fail = True
                    break
                rfound = found_the_W(free_sides)
                if rfound:
                    number_of_dice = new_nr_of_dice(hand, pick_one)
                    min_tiles_list = min_tiles_calc(TILES)
                    if score_high(score, min_tiles_list[0]) or steal_possible(score, stealList):
                        if not players[playerID].human:
                            if survival_rate(free_sides, number_of_dice) > THRESHOLD:
    # print(THRESHOLD, survival_rate(free_sides, number_of_dice) )
                                stay_in_turn = True
                            else:
    #                            #print(f'{survival_rate(free_sides, number_of_dice)} is less than {THRESHOLD}')
                                stay_in_turn = False

                        else:
                            # keep rolling or stop for humans
                            stay_in_turn = stop_rolling_again_question()

                    if stay_in_turn:
                        #print('survival prob : ' + str(survival_rate(free_sides, number_of_dice)) + '%')
                        continue
                    else:
                        break
                continue

    # here doing the stuff after finishing the turn
            if not fail:
                if steal_possible(score, stealList):
                    print(f'succesful steal {score} from {players[stealList.index(score)].name}' )
                    # ready to steal
                    # remove at other player
                    players[stealList.index(score)].own_tiles.remove(score)
                    # add at current player
                    players[playerID].own_tiles.append(score)

                else:
                    tilenr = find_tile(TILES, score)
                    TILES.remove(tilenr)
                    players[playerID].own_tiles.append(tilenr)
                    update_stealList(players, stealList)
            else:
                print(f'{players[playerID].name} died.')
                #print(f'fail, because {score} is too low or no R : {not(found_the_W(free_sides))}')
                TILES = remove_last_tile(TILES)
                if players[playerID].own_tiles:
                    tileback = players[playerID].own_tiles.pop(-1)
                    TILES = give_back_tile(tileback, TILES)
                    update_stealList(players, stealList)

            number_of_dice, free_sides, score = reset_vars()
            print(f'Tiles on the table : {TILES}')
            for each_player in players:
                print(f'{each_player.name} : {each_player.own_tiles}')
    #        #print(players[playerID].name, TILES, players[playerID].own_tiles)
            stay_in_turn = True
    #        #print(f'player = {players[playerID].name}')
            print('\n')
            if players[playerID].human:
                waiting_a_moment = input('\n')
            playerID = next_player(players, playerID)
            print(f'next player will be {players[playerID].name} and his tiles \
    are {players[playerID].own_tiles}')
            stealList = update_stealList(players, stealList)
            print(f'steal list is now {stealList}')
        overallWinners.append(most_worms(players))

    #   fill df with results
    #    dfdict = {cols[0] : (albert.own_tiles > boris.own_tiles), cols[1] : (boris.own_tiles > albert.own_tiles), 'throw_number' : throw_number,\
    #              'turn_number' : turn_number, 'threshold' : THRESHOLD}
    #    df = df.append(dfdict, ignore_index = True)
    #    dfdict = {}

        TILES, players[playerID].own_tiles, throw_number, turn_number, winnaar = reset_tiles(playerID)
        winner_count(overallWinners, players)
        print('\n\n\n\n\n')
```

Comment: With regard to "I feel like reinventing the wheel" do you want to keep your implementations, or would you be happy to see functions you can use that do what you've programed?

Comment: To be more specific,  I run the risk of making wrong habits in coding. I'm very open to suggestions which could improve my understanding and improve my code ;-)

Comment: Ok, in that case I won't add the [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] tag. :)

Comment: You shouldn't have edited the code after getting an answer. See here for details: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

A few general points that I noticed

- Place all the functions at the top and then the main function beneath. I couldn't understand how you were getting some of your values but realised you made main() block calls in between functions

Rather than:

```
def function1():
    ...

[code]...

def funciton2():
    ...

[more code]...
```

say

```
def function1():
    ...

def function2():
    ...


[code]....
```

- It is good practice to put all of your "out of block" code in a function entitled `if __name__ == "__main__"` This means that if the code is imported by another function, it won't run automatically

```
def function1():
    ...

def function2():
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__"
    [code]....
```

- Rather than: `for i in range (0, 10)` say `for i in range(10)` as the 0 is implicit
- This code

```
number_of_games = input(f'Number of games? For auto players mainly ')
number_of_games = int(number_of_games)
```

can be re-written as

```
number_of_games = int(input(f'Number of games? For auto players mainly '))
```

As I am a newbite too, I think I will leave other suggestion to more experienced users but I try and offer what I can

Comment: Thank you EML! I improved my code with your suggestions

Comment: Great! As point of notice for the future normally on this site code changes shouldn't take place as an edit (they should be a new post). As the changes were mainly structural though, and as no one else has commented yet I'm sure it's fine :)

Comment: Yeah I understand, it's just that I thought it would make it easier for others to read and understand my code.